# UILabels go Opaque on PDF if UILable background Color Set to Default

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uiwebview

I have a bit of strange one here

Im rendering a `PDF` in `UIWebView`.  All was good until iOS9.  Since then while the resulting `PDF` file is fine when previewing on device and viewed on desktop, when printed, or exported as `PDF` from a desktop (even though it's already a pdf) most of the `UILabels` are opaque boxes taking the colour of the text on the resulting print out.  This is completely random.  ie. Two `UILabel`s next to each other on the print out with exactly the same characteristics will appear differently.  One as expected, one solid black or `UILabel` color.   I have extensively looked for any common factors on why it chooses to black out some boxes and not on and there is none.  Converting the `PDF` to a `png` on desktop will prevent issue.  Printing direct from `AirPrint` the file prints as expected.

Manually setting the `UIlabel` background colour from default to any colour in IB fixes the issue. Or subclassing the label and manually adding any colour except clear. Checking and adjusting thousands of UIlabels in IB is not an ideal solution.

**Rendering PDF**

```
NSData *pdfData = [self createPdfWithPages:pagesArray];
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(pdfDone:) withObject:pdfData waitUntilDone:YES];

- (NSData *)createPdfWithPages:(NSArray *)pages {


    NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

    component *firstPage = pages[0];

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, firstPage.contentView.bounds, nil);

    for (int i = 0; i < pages.count; i++) {
        component *thisPage = pages[i];
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(thisPage.contentView.bounds, nil);

        CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        [thisPage.contentView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];
    }

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    return pdfData;
}


- (void)pdfDone:(NSData *)data {

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    self.pdfData = data;


    [self.webView loadData:self.pdfData MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:baseURL];



}
```